# Is there any easier way to view UIImageView programmatically?

Tags: swift, function, uiimageview, uiimage

I have 8 buttons and I want to display a picture every time I press the buttons.

What I wonder is, do I need to have 8 functions to display these images?
Or is there any easier ways?

Here is how I've done it, it works as it should, but I do not want to repeat the same things over and over again?

```
var imageView1:UIImageView!
var imageView2:UIImageView!
var imageView3:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showImage1()
    showImage2()
    showImage3()
    tapGestureRecognizerFunc()

  }

 @objc func button1Tap() {
    if self.imageView1.isHidden {
       self.imageView1.isHidden = false            
    }else{
       self.imageView1.isHidden = true
    }
}
@objc func button2Tap() {
    if self.imageView2.isHidden {
       self.imageView2.isHidden = false            
    }else{
       self.imageView2.isHidden = true
    }

}
@objc func button3Tap() {
    if self.imageView3.isHidden {
       self.imageView3.isHidden = false            
    }else{
       self.imageView3.isHidden = true
    }

}
func showImage1() {
    imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 271, y: 8, width: 29, height: 29))
    imageView1.image = UIImage(named: "Done.png")
    imageView1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    View1.addSubview(imageView1)
    imageView1.isHidden = true
}
func showImage2() {
    imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 271, y: 8, width: 29, height: 29))
    imageView2.image = UIImage(named: "Done.png")
    imageView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    View2.addSubview(imageView2)
    imageView2.isHidden = true
}
func showImage3() {
    imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 271, y: 8, width: 29, height: 29))
    imageView2.image = UIImage(named: "Done.png")
    imageView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    View3.addSubview(imageView2)
    imageView2.isHidden = true
}
func tapGestureRecognizerFunc () {        
    let exercise1Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(button1Tap))
    exercise1Tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    View1.addGestureRecognizer(exercise1Tap)

    let exercise2Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(button2Tap))
    exercise2Tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    View2.addGestureRecognizer(exercise2Tap)

    let exercise3Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(button3Tap))
    exercise3Tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    View3.addGestureRecognizer(exercise3Tap)

}
```

yes i'm newbie

Comment: You should use an outlet collection instead of 3 different IBOutlets.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know, where and how you create the Buttons it is difficult to answer.
The following is just a tip.

1. You should use an array of UIImageView
2. Your callback should use the Form buttonAction(sender : UIButton)
3. You could use a tag for the button to get the number of the corresponding button

For example:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var imageviews : [UIImageView] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 1...8 {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        view.addSubview(imageview)
        imageview.tag = i
        imageviews.append(imageview)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i)*50.0, width: 100, height: 30))
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.tag = i
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender : UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag
    print("Button \(index) pressed")

    imageviews[index].isHidden = !imageviews[index].isHidden
}
```

}

Comment: I have made the buttons programmatically and I have now edited the code. 
It is the same image, not display different images.

Comment: This is a good answer. Use the same selector for all of the buttons, and use the button's tag to distinguish what to do, using a switch statement.